# How to make flutter app UI responsive for different screen sizes [Flutter]?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, responsive-design, sizer

I tried these packages Sizer/screenUtil for making responsive but its not doing the same as i want. Plz help me to get out from this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you try using MediaQuery class?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Issue solved with screenutil package. Thanks for answering my question. But it solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `mainAxisAlignment:` with the property such as `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,` or like `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` on the `Row()` or `Column()` you're using .
it should be at least usable while the flutter packages like `ScreenUtil()` or `Sizer()` didnt work, and also `Note: This plugin is still under development, and some APIs might not be available yet.` this msg is written on the **flutter.pub.get**  website so its better to use others while it isnt working properly.